# Copy list initialisation and explicit constructor allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, clang, language-lawyer

I am using the following code in VS2013 and it compiles.

```
explicit QIcon(const QString &fileName); // file or resource name
void setWindowIcon(const QIcon &icon);
```

I call the function like this:

```
setWindowIcon({ "icon.png" });
```

However in Clang 3.7.1 it fails with:

> error chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization

I read in other questions that in the C++ standard, §13.3.1.7 [over.match.list], the following is stated:

> In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the
>   initialization is ill-formed.

Is VS2013 wrong in allowing this code to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, VS2013 is wrong in allowing the code to compile.

The important rule is in `[over.ics.list]` (quote from N3337):

> `[over.ics.list]/1]:` When an argument is an initializer list (8.5.4), it is not an expression and special rules apply for converting
>   it to a parameter type.
>
> `[over.ics.list]/3]:` Otherwise, if the parameter is a non-aggregate class X and overload resolution per 13.3.1.7 chooses a single
>   best constructor of X to perform the initialization of an object of type X from the argument initializer list, the
>   implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence. If multiple constructors are viable but
>   none is better than the others, the implicit conversion sequence is the ambiguous conversion sequence. **User-defined conversions are allowed for conversion of the initializer list elements to the constructor parameter
>   types except as noted in 13.3.3.1**.

`13.3.3.1` outlines implicit conversion sequences, which references `[class.conv.ctor]` regarding user-defined conversions:

> `[class.conv.ctor]/1:` A constructor declared **without the function-specifier explicit** specifies a conversion from the types of its
>   parameters to the type of its class. Such a constructor is called a converting constructor.

So the constructor must not be marked `explicit` if it should be used for this form of initialization.